# How to use useDraggable / useSortable hooks of dnd-kit library properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, dnd-kit

I'm trying to create a simple calculator with React and dnd-kit. Elements of calculator can be dragged to droppable area and can be sorted inside of it. You can see a problem on the gif: when I drag element from left side to droppable area, there is no animation of dragging but element can be dropped to area. And inside of droppable area elements can be beautifly sorted with animation of dragging.

So, I need drag animation to work when I drag elements from left side to droppable area.

[image]

Code for App component:

```
const App: FC = () => {

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState('Constructor')

    const [droppedElems, setDroppedElems] = useState<CalcElemListInterface[]>([])

    const handleActiveSwitcher = (id: string) => {
        setSelected(id)
    }

    const deleteDroppedElem = (item: CalcElemListInterface) => {
        const filtered = [...droppedElems].filter(elem => elem.id !== item.id)
        setDroppedElems(filtered)
    }

    const leftFieldStyles = cn(styles.left, {
        [styles.hidden]: selected === 'Runtime'
    })

    const calcElementsList = calcElemListArray.map((item) => {

        const index = droppedElems.findIndex(elem => elem.id === item.id)
        const layoutDisabledStyle = index !== -1

        return (
            <CalcElemLayout 
                key={item.id} 
                id={item.id} 
                item={item}
                layoutDisabledStyle={layoutDisabledStyle}
            />
        )
    })

    const handleDragEnd = (event: DragEndEvent) => {

        const { id, list }  = event.active.data.current as CalcElemListInterface
        const elem = {id, list}

        if (event.over && event.over.id === 'droppable') {
            setDroppedElems((prev) => {
                return [...prev, elem]
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.layout}>
            <div className={styles.top}>
                <Switcher
                    selected={selected}
                    handleActiveSwitcher={handleActiveSwitcher}
                />
            </div>
            <DndContext
                onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
            >
                <div className={styles.content}>
                    <div className={leftFieldStyles}>
                        {calcElementsList}
                    </div>
                    <DropElemLayout
                        deleteDroppedElem={deleteDroppedElem}
                        selected={selected}
                        droppedElems={droppedElems}
                        setDroppedElems={setDroppedElems}
                    />
                </div>
            </DndContext>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Code for droppable area:

```
const DropElemLayout: FC<DropElemLayoutInterface> = ({ selected, droppedElems, deleteDroppedElem, setDroppedElems }) => {

    const { isOver, setNodeRef } = useDroppable({
        id: 'droppable'
    })

    const sensors = useSensors(
        useSensor(PointerSensor),
        useSensor(KeyboardSensor, {
            coordinateGetter: sortableKeyboardCoordinates,
        })
    )

    const style = {
        backgroundColor: (isOver && !droppedElems.length) ? '#F0F9FF' : undefined,
    }

    const droppedRuntimeElemList = droppedElems.map((item) => {

        const layoutEnabledStyle = droppedElems.length ? true : false

        return (
            <CalcElemLayout 
                key={item.id}
                id={item.id}
                item={item}
                deleteDroppedElem={deleteDroppedElem} 
                selected={selected}
                layoutEnabledStyle={layoutEnabledStyle}
            />
        )
    })

    const droppedElemList = !droppedElems.length
        ?
            <div className={styles.rightContent}>
                <Icon name="#drop"/>
                <p>Перетащите сюда</p>
                <span>любой элемент</span>
                <span>из левой панели</span>
            </div>
        :
            droppedRuntimeElemList

    const className = !droppedElems.length ? styles.right : styles.left

    const handleDragEnd = (event: DragEndEvent) => {
        if (event.active.id !== event.over?.id) {
            setDroppedElems((items: CalcElemListInterface[]) => {
                const oldIndex = items.findIndex(item => item.id === event.active?.id)
                const newIndex = items.findIndex(item => item.id === event.over?.id)
                return arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex)
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <DndContext
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd} 
            sensors={sensors} 
            collisionDetection={closestCenter}
        >
            <div 
                ref={setNodeRef} 
                className={className}  
                style={style}
            >
                <SortableContext
                    items={droppedElems}
                    strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}
                >
                    {droppedElemList}
                </SortableContext>
            </div>
        </DndContext>
    )
}
```

Code for Element itself:

```
const CalcElemLayout: FC<CalcElemLayoutInterface> = ({ item, id, deleteDroppedElem, selected, layoutDisabledStyle, layoutEnabledStyle }) => {

    const { current } = useAppSelector(state => state.calculator)

    // const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, isDragging } = useDraggable({
    //     id: id,
    //     data: {...item},
    //     disabled: selected === 'Runtime'
    // })

    const {
        attributes,
        listeners,
        setNodeRef,
        transform,
        transition,
        isDragging
    } = useSortable({
        id: id,
        data: {...item},
        disabled: selected === 'Runtime'
    })

    const style = {
        transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform),
        transition: transition
    } 

    const handleDeleteDroppedElem = () => {
        deleteDroppedElem?.(item)
    }

    const doubleClickCondition = selected === 'Constructor' ? handleDeleteDroppedElem : undefined

    const layoutStyle = cn(styles.elemLayout, {
        [styles.operators]: item.id === 'operators',
        [styles.digits]: item.id === 'digits',
        [styles.equal]: item.id === 'equal',
        [styles.disabled]: layoutDisabledStyle,
        [styles.enabled]: layoutEnabledStyle,
    })

    const buttonList = item.list?.map(elem => (
        <Button 
            key={elem.name} 
            elem={elem.name}
            selected={selected!}
        />
    ))

    const resultStyle = cn(styles.result, {
        [styles.minified]: current.length >= 10
    })

    const elemList = item.id === 'result'
        ? 
            <div className={resultStyle}>{current}</div>
        :
            buttonList

    const overlayStyle = {  
        opacity: '0.5',
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div 
                ref={setNodeRef} 
                className={layoutStyle}
                onDoubleClick={doubleClickCondition}
                style={style}
                {...attributes}
                {...listeners}
            >
                {elemList}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm just getting acquainted with `dnd-kit`, myself, but one thing I believe you need is the `DragOverlay` element within the App component's `DndContext`.  I believe `DragOverlay` will contain the layout+styling for the draggable _while_ it's being dragged.

Comment: @benJephunneh, thx, I resolved that question already. Yes you are right, that was about DragOverlay component.

Comment: *I must have accidentally added my following comment as an answer.  My apologies.*

I figured you probably had, but thought I'd add a thought if it could help others who came with the same question. If you have time, would you mind creating an answer to your question? I've still only lightly touched the package so it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `DragOverlay` component properly in Element like so:

```
const CalcElemLayout: FC<CalcElemLayoutInterface> = ({ item, id, deleteDroppedElem, selected, layoutDisabledStyle, layoutEnabledStyle }) => {

    const { current } = useAppSelector(state => state.calculator)

    const {
        attributes,
        listeners,
        setNodeRef,
        transform,
        transition,
        isDragging
    } = useSortable({
        id: id,
        data: {...item},
        disabled: selected === 'Runtime',
    })

    const handleDeleteDroppedElem = () => {
        deleteDroppedElem?.(item)
    }

    const doubleClickCondition = selected === 'Constructor' ? handleDeleteDroppedElem : undefined

    const layoutStyle = cn(styles.elemLayout, {
        [styles.operators]: item.id === 'operators',
        [styles.digits]: item.id === 'digits',
        [styles.equal]: item.id === 'equal',
        [styles.disabled]: layoutDisabledStyle,
        [styles.enabled]: layoutEnabledStyle,
        [styles.transparent]: isDragging 
    })

    const style = {
        transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform),
        transition: transition
    } 

    const buttonList = item.list?.map(elem => (
        <Button 
            key={elem.name} 
            elem={elem.name}
            selected={selected!}
        />
    ))

    const resultStyle = cn(styles.result, {
        [styles.minified]: current.length >= 10
    })

    const elemList = item.id === 'result'
        ? 
            <div className={resultStyle}>{current}</div>
        :
            buttonList

    const dragOverlayContent = isDragging 
        ?
            <div 
                className={layoutStyle} 
                style={{
                    opacity: isDragging ? '1' : '',
                    boxShadow: isDragging ? '0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)' : ''
                }}
            >
                {elemList}
            </div> 
        : 
            null

    return (
        <>
            <div 
                ref={setNodeRef} 
                className={layoutStyle}
                onDoubleClick={doubleClickCondition}
                style={style}
                {...attributes}
                {...listeners}
            >
                {elemList}
            </div>
            <DragOverlay dropAnimation={null}>
                {dragOverlayContent}
            </DragOverlay>
        </>
    )
}
```